# MySQL - Featch Records with limit in one table

Tags: mysql

I have one table with 3 fields e.g.

Name, Team Name, Player_Number

there is multiple team and I want to fetch 2 member from each team.

Please share with fast solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from TableName s where (select count(*) from TableName a where a.TeamName = s.TeamName and a.Player_Number >= s.Player_Number) <= 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response...it fine perfect as required... :-)

Comment: If this helped solving you problem please up-vote.